# In Roboguice, where can I find @ContentView?

Tags: android, roboguice

I'm trying out Robguice's Astroboy example and one of the first lines of code in the startin activity is @ContentView annotation which is supposed to be found in the "roboguice.inject.*" package. On the Javadoc on the project home, it's not found. Is the example code outdated? Or is @ContentView deprecated?

Comment: It's there, no? http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/source/browse/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/inject/ContentView.java

Wait, it seems to be gone in 1.1. It's present in 2.0b4 though. They're in the middle of releasing 2.0, so maybe they have updated the samples already.

Comment: As a first-timer, I followed whatever public steps were available for 1.12. I guess I try out 2.x see if the tutorials will resolve.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the @ContentView in particular. However, I would suggest that you start using a 2.0 beta right away, the changes from 1.x are pretty significant, and pretty much required if you want to use any of the new things like fragments.

Comment: Trying out right now, but comes with no instructions =(

Comment: Looks like the examples on the project home are up to date but the instructions to download and install are out of date. 2.0x works with the Astroboy example I have been trying to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ContentView is new to 2.0.  The samples are up to date for 2.0, but you're right the wiki is out of date.

2.0 is currently in [Release Candiate phase](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/roboguice/FY-ST2KIL4k/SiWgWYlp2hIJ), and release of the final version is expected relatively soon, so as Mark suggests I also recommend that you try starting with 2.0 instead of 1.1.

Documentation remains a little sparse on 2.0, but it will improve as we march toward the final release.  Keep on eye on the "2.0 (in progress)" section of the wiki, which has just recently seen some additional content added to the Installation and Tutorial sections of that page.

StackOverflow as well as the forum (available as a link on the main [RoboGuice](http://roboguice.org) project page) are great places to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sources for Robo-Guice 2.0 sources.jar at
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.roboguice/roboguice/2.0